# Windows Shell Script to scan folder & copy file

Tags: windows, shell, file, automation, copy

I would like to loop throught folder & its subfolders & start scnanning and copying a file to specific location within each folder

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, can't comment with less than 50 reputation, have to answer instead.

Are you looking for a certain file type to copy or you want to copy everything from one folder to another? Or, if you find a file of interest, you want to create a new folder and copy it to there?

If you could specify these things, it will be a little easier to provide an answer.

Thanks, Tim.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you have to copy a specific file or file type into a specific dir.

You can try find command with copying specific file into your directory .

find /source_dir/ -type f -name "filename_or_type" -exec cp -t /destination_dir/ {} \;